# How to print out the contents of a tuple without commas or parantheses?

Tags: python

The program prints out `Peter: Number of completed courses: 2 ('Introduction to programming', 3), ('Math', 5)`

But I want it to print out without the parentheses or commas, in my code I tried to do it like `*students[name],sep=", ")` but it only removed the brackets only.

```
def add_student(students,name):
    students[name] = set()

def print_student(students, name):
    
    if name not in students:
        print(f"{name} does not exist in the database")
    else:
        print(f"{name}:")
        print(f"Number of completed courses: {len(students[name])}")
        print(*students[name],sep=', ')
        total_score = 0
        for course in students[name]:   
            total_score += course[1]
        try:
            print(f"average grade : {total_score/len(students[name])}")
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("no completed courses")
                 
    
def add_course(students,name, course:tuple):
    if course[1] == 0:
        return 0
    students[name].add(course)
    
    
students = {}
add_student(students,"Ryan")
add_student(students,"Chris")
add_student(students,"Peter")
add_course(students,"Ryan",("Linear Algebra",9))
add_course(students,"Peter",("Math",5))
add_course(students,"Peter",("Program",0))
add_course(students,"Peter", ("Introduction to programming",3))
print_student(students,"Peter")
print_student(students,"Ryan")
```

Comment: Why did you think that using `sep=", "` did not print commas? Have you tried using something else as `sep`, which is not a comma?

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you are looking for

```py
for course in students[name]:
    print(f"{course[0]} ({course[1]})")
```

output:

```
Introduction to programming (3)
Math (5)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this helped me with a lot of the programs that I was working on

Comment: You are welcome I am glad I could have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

A tuple is always ordered and unchangeable.

When you add courses down below in your code you are giving an argument as a tuple

```
add_course(students,"Peter",("Program",0))
#                           (tupItem0, tupItem1)  <-- The basic form of a tuple
```

By simply printing a tuple you get the entire structure

```
"('Program',0)"
```

You get data out of a tuple like you do a list

```
foo = ('Program',0)
bar = foo[0] # Bar is now "Program"
```

In your program when you do this:

```
print(*students[name],sep=', ')
```

You are printing the entire list of tuples. For explanation purposed I'm going to do it like the following.

```
outString = ""

for item in students[name]:
  outString += item[0] + ", "

print(outString[:-2])
```

Which should get you all of the courses out of your data structure

```
Math, Introduction to programming
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the content of a tuple with a simple separator, use join() as in:

```
print(" ".join(my_tuple))
```

will show the contents with spaces between.  If you want them 'butt up' to each other...

```
print("".join(my_tuple))
```

With a 'nice' comma-space separator...

```
print(", ".join(my_tuple))
```